# Find the joint CDF given joint PDF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

Let be $$f(x,y)=24y(1-x-y) \ \text{ if } x,y\geq 0, x+y<1; 0 \text{ elsewere}$$

Find de CDF, $F(x,y)$.

Solution:

$F(x,y)=0$ for $(x,y)$ in quadrants II, III and IV.

Let be $R$ the region suh that $x,y\geq 0, x+y<1$.

If $(x,y)\in R$, 
$$F(x,y)=\int_0^x\int_0^y24v(1-u-v)dvdu=12xy^2-6x^2y^2-8xy^3. $$

what would be the integration limits for points outside $ R $?

Answer (score 1):

The interval you require is:

$$\{{\langle u,v\rangle:} {{0\leq u\leq \min[x,1],} {0\leq v\leq \min[y, 1-u]}}\}$$